Python - Tree View Dynamic Sizing but also not dynamically sizing
I'm sure the title is confusing but here is the description:
I have a Python GUI program that has a Tree View to log messages.
When the user presses a Toggle Settings button, a lot of the elements under the Tree View get removed and the GUI shrinks. This, in turn, is shrinking my Tree View. I do not want this to happen.
However, I do still want the Tree View to shrink or expand dynamically whenever the user manually is resizing the entire GUI window.
Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Most of my attempts to set the Tree View size as a static place x and y for some reason still outputs a tree view that resizes anyways when pressing the Toggle Settings button.
Here's my specific area of code currently dealing with this:
        global settings_hidden
        if settings_hidden:
            app.geometry("1000x975")
            tree.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.01, relwidth=0.98, relheight=0.45)
            run_backup_button.place(relx=0.025, rely=0.95, anchor="w")
            save_settings_button.place(relx=0.025, rely=0.97)
            toggle_button.place(relx=0.15, rely=0.97)
            start_button.place(relx=0.15, rely=0.95, anchor="w")
            stop_button.place(relx=0.26, rely=0.95, anchor="w")
            profile_frame.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.95, anchor="w")
            for info in interval_positions:
                widget = info['widget']
                widget.place(relx=info['relx'], rely=info['rely'])
            for widget, info in zip(all_widgets, original_positions):
                widget.place(relx=info['relx'], rely=info['rely'], relwidth=info.get('relwidth'), relheight=info.get('relheight'))
            update_widget_visibility()
        else:
            original_positions.clear()
            interval_positions.clear()
            run_backup_button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
            save_settings_button.grid(row=1, column=1)
            toggle_button.grid(row=1, column=2)
            start_button.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")
            stop_button.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="w")
            profile_frame.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="w")
            app.geometry("1000x600")
            tree.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="nsew")
            for widget in all_widgets:
                info = widget.place_info()
                original_positions.append({
                    'widget': widget,
                    'relx': float(info.get('relx', 0)),
                    'rely': float(info.get('rely', 0)),
                    'relwidth': float(info.get('relwidth', 1) or 1) if 'relwidth' in info and info.get('relwidth') else None,
                    'relheight': float(info.get('relheight', 1) or 1) if 'relheight' in info and info.get('relheight') else None
                })
            for widget, info in zip(interval_widgets, interval_positions):
                widget_info = info
                widget = widget_info['widget']
                widget.place_forget()
            for widget in all_widgets:
                widget.place_forget()
        settings_hidden = not settings_hidden

The if settings_hidden section is basically back to the default view, how the program opens in the first place. The section after the else is for when the user presses the Toggle Settings button to hide elements and shrink the GUI to include only the Tree View and a few buttons directly underneath.
Additionally, in case it is needed, here is the initialization/creation of the Tree View in my code:
    tree = ttk.Treeview(app, columns=columns, show='headings')
    tree.heading("Time", text="Time")
    tree.heading("Message", text="Message")
    tree.heading("FilePath", text="File Path")
    tree.column("Time", width=125)
    tree.column("Message", width=250)
    tree.column("FilePath", width=600)
    tree.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.01, relwidth=0.98, relheight=0.45)

